# Told to wait for letter of appointment later in the day, I am still waiting a week later

Tags: job-offer

I received an email a week ago telling me that I was successful in the position I had been interviewed for and the person who notified me that said they would be sending a letter later in the day. Unfortunately I have been waiting for a full week since then. the company is not big and the decision making organs are not that many. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately I have been waiting for a full week since then. the
>   company is not big and the decision making organs are not that many.
>   What should I do?

Call, talk to the appropriate person (HR or hiring manager), and ask if there has been a hangup.

A full week is a reasonable amount of time to wait, unless you were told it would take longer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is being sent by post and normal post takes longer than a week, wait. If not, contact them and ask politely for an update.

Answer (score 0):

By you using email and letter, I can only assume when you said "letter" you meant a physical mail?

If so, are you certain you gave them the right mailing address on your resume/application? They may have sent it to the wrong address.

I like the advice of everyone else to call them up.